# java sudoku backtracking recursive

Tags: java, recursion, sudoku, backtracking

hey i have worte this program to solve sudoko but it just workd for a few cells of sudoku matrix and for other cells returns 0 . can u understand whats wrong with this?
i am new in java coding and it really hurts not to be able to write a simple program.

```
public class sudoku {

static int sud[][] = new int[9][9];

public static void main(String args[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            sud[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    solve(sud);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            System.out.print(sud[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

public static boolean solve(int[][] sud) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (sud[i][j] != 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
                if (!used(i, j, x)) {
                    sud[i][j] = x;
                    if (solve(sud)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

public static boolean isinrow(int i, int j, int x) {
    for (int t = 0; t < 9; t++) {
        if (sud[i][t] == x) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isincol(int i, int j, int x) {
    for (int t = 0; t < 9; t++) {
        if (sud[t][j] == x) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

public static boolean isinsq(int sr, int sc, int x) {
    for (sr = 0; sr < 3; sr++) {
        for (sc = 0; sc < 3; sc++) {
            if (sud[sr][sc] == x) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static boolean used(int i, int j, int x) {
    if (!isinrow(i, j, x)) {
        if (!isincol(i, j, x)) {
            if (!isinsq(i - (i % 3), j - (j % 3), x)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: this is output :  123456789
456789000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000
000000000

Comment: Comments are your friend.  Learn that lesson now!

Answer (score 1):

your problem is in this function you were doing

```
 public static boolean isinsq(int sr, int sc, int x) {
    for ( sr = 0; sr < 3; sr++) {
         //  ^ you are reseting the value of sr that you pass in
          //   effectivel making it so that you always check the first square
        for (  sc = 0; sc < 3; sc++) {
               // ^ same here    
            if (sud[sr][sc] == x) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

this was resetting sr back to 0 so you only ever checked the top left corner not the coordinates that you were passing in. you should have done something like:

```
public static boolean isinsq(int xcorner, int ycorner, int x) {
    for (int sr = xcorner; sr < 3; sr++) {
           //^ here w create a new variable with the starting value that you passed in
        for ( int sc = ycorner; sc < 3; sc++) {
                   //^ here w create a new variable with the starting value that you passed in
            if (sud[sr][sc] == x) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

as an asside your Double nested for loop in solve is unnecessary and adds a bunch of overhead. Instead of looking for the next open spot why not assume they are all open and check to see if they aren't this way your recursion will take care of that iterating for you. Consider something like this (its also more simple....at least to me)

```
bool solve(int[][] sud, int x, int y)
{
//here need to make sure that when x>9 we set x to 0 and increment y
//also if x == 9 and y == 9 need to take care of end condition

if(sud[x][y]==0) //not a pre given value so we are ok to change it
{
    for(int i =1; i<10; ++i)
    {
        sud[x][y] = i;
        if(validBoard(sud)) //no point in recursing further if the current board isnt valid
        {
            if(solve(sud, x+1,y))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    return solve(x+1,y);
}
return false;
}
```

I left some areas that need filling (where's the fun in having me do it for you :). And as everyone else has suggested you should use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: becuz of if (!isinsq(i - (i % 3), j - (j % 3), x)) that will ckeck all the squares, i did what u said but my output is the same :(

Comment: oh i got it! now its better with a better output:))

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that `isInSq` is always going to check the top left square since you wipe out your arguments when you go into the loop. You should be going from `sr` to `sr + 2` and the same for `sc`. I don't think that's the only problem, but it looks like a good place to start.

As another tip, I would fix your variable names. You may be able to understand them, but it make it a lot harder for others to read.